# Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. -enterframe.Trying to get palayer out of maze

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, null, maze

i'm making a simple game and i'm still learning as3 i want to hit test object on the stage , player with box if hittestobject gotoframe or scene all the objects are on the stage with corect instancename, maintimeline as3 below everything works fine but i get the null error.
it is a maze game.

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;


var rightArrow:Boolean = false;
var leftArrow:Boolean = false;
var upArrow:Boolean = false;
var downArrow:Boolean = false;
var speed:int = 20;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, stage_onKeyDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, stage_onKeyUp);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, stage_onEnterFrame);

function stage_onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) rightArrow = true;
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) leftArrow = true;
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) upArrow = true;
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) downArrow = true;
}
function stage_onKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) rightArrow = false;
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) leftArrow = false;
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) upArrow = false;
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) downArrow = false;
}
function stage_onEnterFrame(event:Event):void {
    var rect:Rectangle = player.getBounds(this);
    var i:int = 0;
    var xBump:int = 0;
    var yBump:int = 0;
    if(rightArrow) {
        xBump = speed;
        for(i = 0; i < speed; i++) {
            if(maze.hitTestPoint(rect.right + i, player.y, true)) {
                xBump = i - 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if(player.hitTestObject(box))
    {
       // Go to next scene
       nextFrame();
    }
    if(leftArrow) {
        xBump = -speed;
        for(i = 0; i < speed; i++) {
            if(maze.hitTestPoint(rect.left - i, player.y, true)) {
                xBump = -i + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    if(upArrow) {
        yBump = -speed;
        for(i = 0; i < speed; i++) {
            if(maze.hitTestPoint(player.x, rect.top - i, true)) {
                yBump = -i + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(downArrow) {
        yBump = speed;
        for(i = 0; i < speed; i++) {
            if(maze.hitTestPoint(player.x, rect.bottom + i, true)) {
                yBump = i - 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    player.x += xBump;
    player.y += yBump;
}
```

Comment: Please post complete stack trace of the error.

Comment: hi this is what i get TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at mazetest3_fla::MainTimeline/stage_onEnterFrame()

Comment: Add the following to the beginning of `stage_onEnterFrame` function: `trace(player)`. If it'll return `null`, check your player instance to have a correct name on the stage.